# Point to Polygon (rectangle)

Tags: cityengine

I have a 2D data for a building, basically a GDB containing wall-polygon, column polygon, Glass-wall polygon. The Door layer inside the building is represented as a point. Is there any way to generate door (rectangle feature) wherever the door-points are placed inside the building. Currently I am manually drawing each door polygon but its a time-consuming task, is there any work-around for doing this as I have thousands of doors to be digitized.